# 'pip install MySQL-python' fails with 'IndexError'

Tags: python, mysql, pip, mysql-python, osx-elcapitan

I'm on OSX El Capitan, using Python 2.7 (Anaconda). Launching the command `pip install MySQL-python` yields:

```
Collecting MySQL-python
  Using cached MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/d2/gd004m2s35z5dlyz9mfn6sc40000gn/T/pip-build-FYvb_T/MySQL-python/setup.py", line 17, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "setup_posix.py", line 53, in get_config
        libraries = [ dequote(i[2:]) for i in libs if i.startswith(compiler_flag("l")) ]
      File "setup_posix.py", line 8, in dequote
        if s[0] in "\"'" and s[0] == s[-1]:
    IndexError: string index out of range
```

None of these worked (exit with same error).

- `pip install mysqlclient`
- `easy_install MySQL-python`

`pip` is up-to-date. I've basically tried to follow all suggestions in related questions, but none succeeded. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Copy from [this blog.](https://notes.wanghao.work/2017-05-20-%E8%A7%A3%E5%86%B3Mysql%E7%9A%84Python%E9%A9%B1%E5%8A%A8%E5%AE%89%E8%A3%85%E5%A4%B1%E8%B4%A5.html)

By finding out the information that `mysql-connector-c`might come to the conclusion that the configuration by brew installation may be incorrect , open the `/usr/local/bin/mysql_config` script to modify some of the contents of it:

```
#Create options
Libs = "-L$pkglibdir "
Libs = "$libs -l"
```

change into:

```
#Create options
Libs = "-L$pkglibdir"
Libs = "$libs -lmysqlclient -lssl -lcrypto"
```

Save
Then re-install mysql-python:

```
pip install mysql-python
```

Comment: You might also need to run `export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib"` and `export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include"` before installing `mysql-python`. See the output of `brew info openssl`

Answer (score 7):

I met same error and solved with following instructions:

1. brew uninstall mysql-connector-c
2. brew install mysql
3. invoke "mysql_config --libs" and confirm its output include correct library options: "-L/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.20/lib -lmysqlclient -lssl -lcrypto"
4. export LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib && pip install mysqlclient

Answer (score 5):

This solved my issue:

```
     brew install mysql@5.7
     brew link --force mysql@5.7
```

Comment: Yes, after installed this version. We also have to follow command `LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib pip install mysql-python`. I successfully installed in macOS 10.13.6.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error while installing `pip install MySql-python`.

Then, I had installed `libmysqlclient-dev` using the command:

`sudo apt install libmysqlclient-dev`

After installing it, I tried again and `pip install MySql-python`
and it worked for me.

Comment: Do you know where I can find the correspondent library for OSX? `brew install mysql` did not change anything, unfortunately.