# Python: How to resolve python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1

Tags: python, mysql, django

I saw answers to a similar problem to mine but no of the answers helped me.
I still have the same issue. I'm sorry if it is duplicated but the other answers do not help me.

I'm stuck with a project in Django where I have to install MySQL-python.
When I'm running `pip install MySQL-Python` I got this error:

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-Ue6URf/MySQL-Python/
```

I used brew as suggested in some answers here but didn't help at all.
I'm using a Mac machine with the last Python3 and the last Django version.
I have MampPro last version which I'm using the MySQL service.

I'm sharing the entire output of the installation:

```
    Collecting MySQL-Python
  Downloading MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip (108kB)
    100% |################################| 112kB 561kB/s 
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/tmp/pip-build-Ue6URf/MySQL-Python/setup.py", line 17, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "setup_posix.py", line 53, in get_config
        libraries = [ dequote(i[2:]) for i in libs if i.startswith(compiler_flag("l")) ]
      File "setup_posix.py", line 8, in dequote
        if s[0] in "\"'" and s[0] == s[-1]:
    IndexError: string index out of range

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-Ue6URf/MySQL-Python/
```

Comment: I saw this questions but that is not fixing my issue I still have the same issue

Answer (score 1):

I resolved my issue, I resolved thanks to this post here in StackOverflow 
[answer for PIP install fail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44309407/7882685)

I had to modify my mysql_config files and do the export part describe in this answer.
After that, I was able to install again doing pip install ...

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below instructions

1. `sudo apt install libmysqlclient-dev`
2. `pip install MySql-python`