# How can I fix this error very time I try type pip install mysql-python

Tags: python, mysql, homebrew

I have been trying to install python-MySQLdb on mac and I keep getting error. I have tried so many alternatives to pass that error.

```
sudo PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/bin/:$PATH pip install mysql-python
Password:
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7.
The directory '/Users/zuhairhallak/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/Users/zuhairhallak/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting mysql-python
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a5/e9/51b544da85a36a68debe7a7091f068d802fc515a3a202652828c73453cad/MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip (108kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 112kB 2.6MB/s 
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/tmp/pip-install-RtF2js/mysql-python/setup.py", line 17, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "setup_posix.py", line 53, in get_config
        libraries = [ dequote(i[2:]) for i in libs if i.startswith(compiler_flag("l")) ]
      File "setup_posix.py", line 8, in dequote
        if s[0] in "\"'" and s[0] == s[-1]:
    IndexError: string index out of range

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-install-RtF2js/mysql-python/
```

I have also ran sudo -H pip install mysql-python and I got different error

13 warnings generated.
  cc -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -Wl,-F. build/temp.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/_mysql.o -L/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.15/lib -lmysqlclient -lssl -lcrypto -o build/lib.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/_mysql.so
  ld: library not found for -lssl
  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
  error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1

---

Failed building wheel for mysql-python
  Running setup.py clean for mysql-python
Failed to build mysql-python
Installing collected packages: mysql-python
  Running setup.py install for mysql-python ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/private/tmp/pip-install-3A8kOd/mysql-python/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /private/tmp/pip-record-TUb4up/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['pip install MySQL-python' fails with 'IndexError'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43543483/pip-install-mysql-python-fails-with-indexerror)

Comment: its not duplicate question but i kept having different errors for each alternative solution i try. Fixed my problem though

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
brew install mysql
sudo -H pip install mysql-python
```

Comment: Could you add some more detail saying what's wrong and how this fixes it? It'll help understanding for the OP and future readers.

Comment: Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip-install-3A8kOd/mysql-python/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/tmp/pip-record-TUb4up/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-install-3A8kOd/mysql-python/

Comment: I got another error After running sudo -H pip install mysql-python

Answer (score 0):

I went to the mysql_config file and opened it up

vi mysql_config

This was correct.

```
Create options:
Libs = "- L $ pkglibdir"
Libs = "$ libs -lmysqlclient -lssl -lcrypto"
```

ran this command in terminal
1. export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib"
2. export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include"
3. pip install mysql-python