# Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 **upgrading setuptools does not work!**

Tags: python, mysql, macos, terminal

I have been trying to install MySQL in python using the following command:

```
pip install MySQL-python
```

However, I receive the following error:

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/78/6x078vmd591d01w_p5l6wtk40000gp/T/pip-install-xBIsBR/MySQL-python/
```

Now, I realize there are many sources that say to simply run this:

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

I have tried this, and I get this:

```
Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (41.0.0)
```

So it seems to me that my `setuptools` are fine, but I am still unable to install MySQL. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you get a different error, I believe this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43543483/pip-install-mysql-python-fails-with-indexerror/44309407#44309407) should be useful. 
Therefore, change the content of `/usr/local/bin/mysql_config` from

```
Libs = "-L $ pkglibdir "
Libs = " $ libs   -l"
```

to

```
Libs = "- L $ pkglibdir"
Libs = "$ libs -lmysqlclient -lssl -lcrypto"
```

and finally re-install `mysql-python`

```
pip install mysql-python
```

Comment: Sorry, I've never gone about editing a script, kind of a newbie. How would I do that? Or if you have a resource for me to look at instead that would also help.

Comment: open the file with a text editor, for example `vi /usr/local/bin/mysql_config` and make the necessary changes.