# Problem in installing MySQL-Python on Mac 10.14.3

Tags: python, mysql, macos, pip

I am unable to install MySQL-python on my Mac. I am getting error as follows:

```
ERROR: Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'/private/tmp/pip-install-y1RoWA/MySQL-Python/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/tmp/pip-record-qvfG3y/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
ERROR: running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7
copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7
creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/MySQLdb
creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/REFRESH.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
running build_ext
building '_mysql' extension
creating build/temp.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7
cc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'final',1) -D__version__=1.2.5 -I/usr/local/Cellar/mysql@5.7/5.7.25/include/mysql -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/_mysql.o
In file included from _mysql.c:44:
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql@5.7/5.7.25/include/mysql/my_config.h:174:9: warning: 'SIZEOF_LONG' macro redefined [-Wmacro-redefined]
#define SIZEOF_LONG      8
        ^
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/pymacconfig.h:54:17: note: previous definition is here
#        define SIZEOF_LONG             4
                ^
In file included from _mysql.c:44:
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql@5.7/5.7.25/include/mysql/my_config.h:179:9: warning: 'SIZEOF_TIME_T' macro redefined [-Wmacro-redefined]
#define SIZEOF_TIME_T    8
        ^
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/pymacconfig.h:57:17: note: previous definition is here
#        define SIZEOF_TIME_T           4
                ^
2 warnings generated.
_mysql.c:287:14: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'Py_ssize_t' (aka 'long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                cmd_argc = PySequence_Size(cmd_args);
                         ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
_mysql.c:317:12: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'Py_ssize_t' (aka 'long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                groupc = PySequence_Size(groups);
                       ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
_mysql.c:470:14: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'Py_ssize_t' (aka 'long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                        int j, n2=PySequence_Size(fun);
                               ~~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
_mysql.c:1127:9: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                len = mysql_real_escape_string(&(self->connection), out, in, size);
                    ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
_mysql.c:1129:9: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                len = mysql_escape_string(out, in, size);
                    ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
_mysql.c:1168:9: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'Py_ssize_t' (aka 'long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
        size = PyString_GET_SIZE(s);
             ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/stringobject.h:92:32: note: expanded from macro 'PyString_GET_SIZE'
#define PyString_GET_SIZE(op)  Py_SIZE(op)
                               ^~~~~~~~~~~
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/object.h:116:56: note: expanded from macro 'Py_SIZE'
#define Py_SIZE(ob)             (((PyVarObject*)(ob))->ob_size)
                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
_mysql.c:1178:9: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                len = mysql_real_escape_string(&(self->connection), out+1, in, size);
                    ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
_mysql.c:1180:9: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                len = mysql_escape_string(out+1, in, size);
                    ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
_mysql.c:1274:11: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'Py_ssize_t' (aka 'long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
        if ((n = PyObject_Length(o)) == -1) goto error;
               ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/abstract.h:434:25: note: expanded from macro 'PyObject_Length'
#define PyObject_Length PyObject_Size
                        ^
_mysql.c:1466:10: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                        len = strlen(buf);
                            ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~
_mysql.c:1468:10: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                        len = strlen(buf);
                            ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~
_mysql.c:1504:11: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                                len = strlen(buf);
                                    ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~
_mysql.c:1506:11: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                                len = strlen(buf);
                                    ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~
13 warnings generated.
cc -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -Wl,-F. build/temp.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/_mysql.o -L/usr/local/Cellar/mysql@5.7/5.7.25/lib -lmysqlclient -lssl -lcrypto -o build/lib.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/_mysql.so
ld: library not found for -lssl
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c 'import setuptools, 
tokenize;__file__='"'"'/private/tmp/pip-install-y1RoWA/MySQL- 
Python/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open) . 
(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', 
'"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' 
install --record /private/tmp/pip-record-qvfG3y/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-install-y1RoWA/MySQL-Python/
```

My mysql-config is as follows:

```
Usage: /usr/local/bin/mysql_config [OPTIONS]
Options:
    --cflags         [-I/usr/local/Cellar/mysql-connector-c/6.1.11/include ]
    --cxxflags       [-I/usr/local/Cellar/mysql-connector-c/6.1.11/include ]
    --include        [-I/usr/local/Cellar/mysql-connector-c/6.1.11/include]
    --libs           [-L/usr/local/Cellar/mysql-connector-c/6.1.11/lib -l ]
    --libs_r         [-L/usr/local/Cellar/mysql-connector-c/6.1.11/lib -l ]
    --plugindir      [/usr/local/Cellar/mysql-connector-c/6.1.11/lib/plugin]
    --socket         [/tmp/mysql.sock]
    --port           [0]
    --version        [6.1.11]
    --variable=VAR   VAR is one of:
            pkgincludedir [/usr/local/Cellar/mysql-connector-c/6.1.11/include]
            pkglibdir     [/usr/local/Cellar/mysql-connector-c/6.1.11/lib]
            plugindir     [/usr/local/Cellar/mysql-connector-c/6.1.11/lib/plugin]
```

My mysql version is as follows:

```
$ mysql --version
 mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.25, for osx10.14 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

I have gone through a several posts related to this, but could not fix.

EDIT: I re-installed xcode by following these two steps:

1. sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
2. xcode-select --install

Now I am getting different error while doing:
   $ sudo pip install MySQL-python

I am getting following error:

```
 ERROR: Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
 ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/private/tmp/pip-install-CbO7Ty/MySQL-python/setup.py", line 17, in <module>
    metadata, options = get_config()
  File "setup_posix.py", line 53, in get_config
    libraries = [ dequote(i[2:]) for i in libs if i.startswith(compiler_flag("l")) ]
  File "setup_posix.py", line 8, in dequote
    if s[0] in "\"'" and s[0] == s[-1]:
IndexError: string index out of range
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in 
/private/tmp/pip-install-CbO7Ty/MySQL-python/
```

EDIT 2: I see someone has posted a question as a probable duplicate of this. FYI, I have applied the approach as suggested in this post (['pip install MySQL-python' fails with 'IndexError'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43543483/pip-install-mysql-python-fails-with-indexerror)) but then I am getting the previous error. So I posted it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmysql%5D+%5Bpip%5D+IndexError%3A+string+index+out+of+range

Comment: @phd I have applied the approach as suggested in the post. But it is not working. I am getting the first type of error. So I posted it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40587558/error-installing-mysql-python-library-not-found-for-lssl

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+ld%3A+library+not+found+for+lssl